# Android : Get String from TextView and pass it to other few activities

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to pass few of string from TextView of activity 1 to activity 2 for addition operation. That was a success.

Now, is it possible to pass the existing strings from activity 1 to activity 3 just by using a button in activity 2 to perform a subtraction operation?

**This is my activity 2, the addition operation**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

String string1 = intent.getStringExtra("no1");
String string2 = intent.getStringExtra("no2");

double addition = Double.parseDouble(string1) + Double.parseDouble(string2);
answer.setText(String.valueOf(addition));
```

**This is my activity 2, the button that will pass the string**

```
public void onClick(View v) {
if (v.getId() == R.id.btnPage2) {        

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();  
String string1 = extras.getString("no1");
String string2= extras.getString("no2");

Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Act3.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

**This is my activity 3, the subtraction operation**

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    String string1 = intent.getStringExtra("no1");
    String string2 = intent.getStringExtra("no2");

    double subtract = Double.parseDouble(string1) - Double.parseDouble(string2);
    answer.setText(String.valueOf(subtract));
```

I have some problem on understanding on how to get the string from other activity. Please help me figure out the right way on getting the string input from other few activity.

Thank you!

Comment: you're already getting string from other activity by using :Intent intent = getIntent();

    String string1 = intent.getStringExtra("no1");

Comment: What should I do then? The first operation, addition run as I want it to be but when I try to click the button to go to the next page to perform the subtraction, they crash.  -  Ahlem Jarrar

Comment: can you please provide the LogCat Message error

Comment: Is that the right logcat? @AhlemJarrar

Comment: No it's not visit these link https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html

Comment: Have you registered the activity in the manifest? Also, post your error logcat

Comment: It's work now. Thanks for replying. The problem is at the ids. I misplace some of them.  @AhlenJarrar

Comment: Yes, the manifest is fine. Thanks for replying.  It's turn out that I misplaced some of the ids. It's work now.  @Shaishav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add

```
intent.putExtra("no1", string1);
intent.putExtra("no2", string2);
```

after

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Act3.class);
```

in activity 2. To add the strings to the intent for activity 3.

Comment: I'm sorry but they still crash @AntonMalyshev

Comment: what's the crash log?

Comment: They work now! I misplaced some of the id. That was my mistake. I add the code you gave. That's really simple. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that Activity 2 has a valid Intent (with extras) from Activity 1 then you need in Activity 2 [putExtras](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtras(android.os.Bundle)) (Bundle) to an Intent that runs Activity 3.

**For example in Activity 2, the button that will pass the string:**

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.btnPage2) {        
         Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Act3.class);
         intent.putExtras(getIntent().getExtras());   

         startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but they still crash too @MikePtr

Comment: It should work! Please make sure that getExtras doesn't return null, please send a stacktrace.

Comment: Yes,  they work now. I misplaced some of the ids. Thank you @MikePtr